# Big O estimate of $\frac{(5x^5+3x^2)(x\log x+x)}{10x^3}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I have this function

$$\frac{(5x^5+3x^2)(x\log x+x)}{10x^3}$$

and I have to give a big O estimate for it and so far here's what I have got.

I know to give a big O estimate, first I have to find the dominant term. In this case, after getting rid of slow increasing terms and simplifying, I am here:

$$\frac{x^3\log_2(x)}{2}+\frac{x^3}{2}$$

Then I can factor a $x^3$ out of the two fractions which I think is dominant term, so then the Big O estimate would be $O(x^3)$. Is this correct? I am mainly confused because of the $\log x$ in the function towards the end.

Thanks!

Comment: Which one is bigger $\log(x)$ or $1$ for large values of $x$?

Comment: This seems like it would have fit better on [CS.SE].

Comment: @jpmc26 Well this question is regarding Big O which is under the tag asymptotics so I thought it would be a perfect fit here.

Comment: @SarahHyland You can write the function in the title itself making it more meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, you see that $x^3\log x$ is bigger than $x^3$. So the function $$\frac{(5x^5+3x^2)(x\log x + x)}{10x^3}$$ is actually $O(x^3\log x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

$O(x^3 \log x)$ will do it.

The function is not bounded by a constant multiple of $x^3$ because $\log x \to\infty$ as $x\to\infty.$

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and edits!

Answer (score 1):

If $\log(x)$ is the natural logarithm, then one can take advantage of $\ln(x) + 1$ by saying $\ln(x) + 1 = \ln(x) + \ln(e) = \ln(e \, x)$ and then
$$\frac{\left(5x^5+3x^2\right)(x\log x+x)}{10x^3} = \frac{1}{10} (5x^3 + 3) \ln( e \, x) \approx \mathcal{O}(\frac{x^{3}}{2} \ln(x)) \approx \mathcal{O}(x^3 \ln(x)).$$

Comment: What is the point of writing $\ln(ex)$ instead of $\ln x \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: That's effectively adding irrelevant, non-leading terms to the asymptotic estimate. I.e., something not to do.

Comment: Writing $\mathcal O(x^3 \ln \sqrt x)$ is also nonstandard, because $\Theta(\ln(\operatorname{poly}(x)) = \Theta(\ln x)$ and so the latter is used always.